# Did Emma Russel change her mind about her initial plan?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, godzilla-king-of-monsters

Initially Emma Russel was with Alan John in *Godzilla: King of Monsters*. Did they have a fallout between them? Did she change her mind about the initial population control plan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godzilla%3A_King_of_the_Monsters_(2019_film)#Plot):

> Emma realizes the destruction Ghidorah and the other Titans will bring
> to the world is much worse than anything that humans could inflict

According to [Fandom](https://villains.fandom.com/wiki/Emma_Russell#Godzilla:_King_of_the_Monsters):

> Emma eventually starts doubting that Jonah's goals are as effective as
> he says they are, and suggests that they quit the operation

From what I remember of the film, it was pretty obvious that Emma changed her mind and decided that the plan was not a good idea. She may have been swayed by her daughter Madison.

Comment: Thanks, Raj. One last thing: what happened with Alan John, did he die somehow?

Comment: I don't remember and may have missed it, but according to fandom he appears in a post-credits scene.